# Extract substrings from file names in a for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to get substrings of file names in a current folder. Later I'm going to pass these as arguments to a certain command but as for now I can't even make echo to work:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (*.mvx) do (
  set a=%%f
  echo %a%
  echo %%a%%
  echo %a:~3,8%
)
endlocal
pause
```

yields results of the kind:

```
C:\1>(
set a=xx-20121213-mvl-0005.mvx
 echo
 echo %a%
 echo ~3,8
)
ECHO is on.
%a%
~3,8
```

the last one is supposed to return "20121213" for the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion to echo your variables, as you have set them in a `for` loop.

You have already included the line to enable it, you just need to turn your `%`'s into `!`'s

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (*.mvx) do (
  set a=%%f
  echo !a!
  echo !a:~3,8!
)
endlocal
pause
```

***Update***

To put the entire script on a one line cmd command you can use

```
cmd /v:on /c "for %f in (*.mvx) do set a=%f && echo !a! && echo !a:~3,8! && pause"
```

Comment: grr, it turned out I should do it not in a batch, but just in console. Do you know the command line equivalent of `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`?

Comment: You want a one line of the batch to use in a prompt?

Comment: well, I need a command which would do the same as the script, but without creating the .cmd. This command will be executed from a program using the functionality of calling OS commands.

Comment: Ok, you can't use delayed expansion in the same way on a cmd prompt though, so it needs a bit of modifying, see my updated answer.